# Rebase data to relative performance with rangeslider in Python Dash Graph update_layout

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python, rangeslider

I am trying to use and adjust the rangeslider property in the update_layout of a Python Dash core component Graph. I like to rebase data to a relative performance chart whenever the rangeslider is changed such that the performance is always measured to the first element in the selected range. I was able to accomplish this by using a RangeSlider as an input for the Graph component. However, I was wondering if this is also possible **only** using the rangeslider property in the Graph component directly without the callback.

I am looking for something similar to this solution in R: https://mgei.github.io/post/rangeslider-plotly/.

```
# Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

from dash import Dash, html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

import plotly.express as px

# Data
T = 100
steps = 10
base = datetime.datetime.today()
date_list = reversed([base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(T)])
test_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(T)/100, index=date_list, columns=['Col1'])
test_data.iloc[0,:] = 0
# App
app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([html.H3('RangeSlider'),
                       dcc.RangeSlider(0, T, steps, count=1, 
                                       marks={i:test_data.index[i].strftime('%d.%m.%y') for i in range(0,T,steps)}, 
                                       id='range_slider'),
                       html.Br(),
                       html.H3('Plot'),
                       dcc.Graph(figure={'data':[]}, id='plot_data'),
                       ],
                      style={'width': '50%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'padding-left':'25%', 'padding-right':'25%'}
                      )

# Callbacks
@app.callback(Output('plot_data', 'figure'),
              Input('range_slider', 'value'))
def plot_data(value):
    if value is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        tmp_data = (1+test_data.iloc[value[0]:value[1],:]).cumprod() * 100
        tmp_data.iloc[0,:] = 100
        tmp_data = tmp_data.sort_index()
        fig = px.line(tmp_data, y=['Col1'])
        fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=True), type='date'))
        fig.update_layout(showlegend=True)
        return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Comment: Just confirming since I'm a little unclear on what you want to achieve, do you want to use the range slider plotly on the Dash without using the range slider on the Dash? Or do you want to use both? I have created an example that uses the plotly slider on top of Dash.

Comment: Thank you. I want to use the range slider plotly on the Dash without using the range slider on the Dash. I want something similar to the Colab code, the only difference is that I like to rebase the data whenever adjusting the slider such that the data always starts at 1.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it did not work is probably due to the fact that the time series data of the test data does not match the time series data of the slider.
My fixes included changing the date in `datetime.date.today()` to a date, changing the date format of the slider to a hyphenated format (unrelated to the failure), expanding the slider to 75% of the browser width because it was too short, and adjusting the margins.

```
# Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

from dash import Dash, html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash

import plotly.express as px

# Data
T = 100
steps = 10
base = datetime.date.today()
date_list = reversed([base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(T)])
test_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(T)/100, index=date_list, columns=['Col1'])
test_data.iloc[0,:] = 0
#fig = px.line(test_data, y=['Col1'])

# App
#app = Dash(__name__)
app = JupyterDash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([html.H3('RangeSlider'),
                       dcc.RangeSlider(0, T, steps, count=1, 
                                       marks={i:test_data.index[i].strftime('%d-%m-%y') for i in range(0,T,steps)}, 
                                       id='range_slider'),
                       html.Br(),
                       html.H3('Plot'),
                       dcc.Graph(figure={'data':[]}, id='plot_data'),
                       ],
                      style={'width': '75%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'padding-left':'10%', 'padding-right':'15%'}
                      )

# Callbacks
@app.callback(Output('plot_data', 'figure'),
              Input('range_slider', 'value'))
def plot_data(value):
    if value is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        tmp_data = (1+test_data.iloc[value[0]:value[1],:]).cumprod() * 100
        tmp_data.iloc[0,:] = 100
        tmp_data = tmp_data.sort_index()
        print(tmp_data)
        fig = px.line(tmp_data, y=['Col1'])
        fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=True), type='date'))
        fig.update_layout(showlegend=True)
        return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False, mode='inline')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I like the slider to change the plotted data, similar to this: https://mgei.github.io/post/rangeslider-plotly/. The plotted data should change when I adjust the slider to a relative performance from the first date of the slider range? I hope that this is a little bit more clear...:)

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you are commenting on, are you saying you want the same thing as the range slider in plotly, I don't think there is such a component available in Dash.

Comment: I was wondering if there is any way to adjust the rangeslider property in the plotly update_layout. Is there any way to rebace the data in the plot based on the info from the rangeslider?

Comment: Plotly's range slider includes show/hide and range settings. See here for [more information](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/). Getting the value of the range slider is not something you can do unless you can catch user events after all. If my answer helps you, please accept the answer.